Debugging Kotlin IOSMain code using Xcode
I have the latest xcode-kotlin plugin install on my XCODE version 15.4. (By the way, the latest version of the xcode-kotlin plugin installed on XCODE 15.4 using brew with no additional install workarounds needed as described in the install procedure!) Using the Xcode-kotlin plugin is certainly a big big help. Setting breakpoints and stepping through the code works great.  The problem is that I'm not able to view the contents of frame variables stored in iosMain.  For example, in my iosMain, I have the following variable defined in the implementation of iOS actual class:
 var pathUrl: NSURL?

The variable is set in the constructor for that class:
     actual constructor(pathname: String) {
         pathUrl = NSURL.URLWithString(pathname)
     }

I'm able to step through the code and break at that line. The problem is that I can't view the value of "pathURL.path" from lldb.  From the lldb console, I can do the following:
 (lldb) frame variable _this->pathUrl
 (ObjHeader *) _this->pathUrl = []

That's fine and dandy, but I want to see the value of the path for that variable. I've tried numerous ways coerce that variable to be a (NSURL *), but I've not found anyway to successfully do that. In this context, NSURL is from Kotlin "platform.Foundation". My understanding is that it's a Kotlin wrapper class for Apples NSURL class. I have no problem seeing variables such as "pathname" which come from the stack.  Please note that I obviously know what I'm setting the path to; I'm just using this as an example and my real problem is that I can't seem to see the value of frame variables contained in the shared "iosMain" if that frame variable is a "platform.Foundation" class. Also note, I tried to view pathUrl.path after its value was set in the constructor.  I also could not view the contents of pathUrl later in another method in which I was referencing pathUrl.
At this time, I think that this is due to a limitation of the Xcode-kotlin plugin because it doesn't have enough information about the "platform.Foundation" symbols. So the fundamental question I'm asking boils down to this:
 1.) Is there a way for me to view the contents of this frame variable using lldb?, or
 2.) Is there a way for me to let Xcode-kotlin plugin know about "platform.Foundation" symbols?


(Context, I wrote the Xcode Kotlin plugin, or at least the main lldb integration. The team has done an excellent job on the install tool and other fixes)
Assuming from this:

That's fine and dandy, but I want to see the value of the path for that variable.

Running your debug commands in the terminal don't help. That's not an "Xcode-Kotlin Plugin" issue. It's a Kotlin lldb issue.
The Xcode-Kotlin plugin doesn't really do any "debugging" work directly. The plugin itself simply informs Xcode that Kotlin is debuggable source code, and initializes the Kotlin lldb script. It also styles the Kotlin code, but that's not important to the core functionality.
The Kotlin lldb script is part of core Kotlin. We did provide the original optimizations to allow it to be usable from a visual editor (Xcode and, at the time, App Code), but the actual lldb functionality is all handled by the lldb script, which is maintained by the Kotlin team. We used to have a "lightly optimized" version that added back in some of the optimizations that they removed (to be fair, they would've been hellish to maintain), but JetBrains put a lot of effort into the lldb script during the "Android Studio KMM Plugin years", so we just use the stock one.
TL;DR There are a few issues with lldb and Kotlin, but without some serious edits to the lldb script, and certainly the Kotlin core code that communicates with the lldb script, there's not a lot we can do.

Kevin, thanks for explaining what's going on.  My hat off to you and the rest of your members on the xcode-kotlin plugin team.  It certainly is a big help in debugging kotlin  from Xcode.
